# Moving an image in android without canvas

Tags: android

How to move an ImageView in android(without using canvas)?? I want to translate an image like an animation but canvas is confusing me :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this one help you.

```
    TranslateAnimation ta = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
    ta.setDuration(300);
    ta.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    yourView.startAnimation(ta);
```

set values as you want and onAnimationEnd() set yourView layoutParams.Set from values with your view current value and after giving to values set yourView according to new x and y value.

Comment: wow thanks.. but the problem is the image came back to its original position after animation..

Comment: You should set images LayoutParams at the and of animation(onAnimationEnd). For example: your images layoutgravity is right and you moved it left with setting toX=0 then at onAnimationEnd change gravity to left

Comment: I am new to android so, can u show me some code to set layout params please??